# drush omega-guard and missing or unreadable gemfiles

Tags: drush, theming

My machine is running Archlinux and and I am new in drush and omega theme.
I have installed drush and then run bundle install to install the dependencies of my subtheme.
When I run drush omega-guard, I get some errors which says the file to import not found or unreadable, while I have installed those gems too.

```
[timmy@MyPC drupal-7.31]$ drush omega-guard
Which theme do you want to run Guard for?
 [0]  :  Cancel                                                                                                                            
 [1]  :  First (Subtheme of Omega) - My first theme.                                                                                      
 [2]  :  Ohm (Subtheme of Omega) - Omega based demonstration theme. Serves as a best-practice reference for the Omega documentation. Ohm  
         will be constantly updated as best practice evolves so shouldnt be used in production.                                          
 [3]  :  Omega - A powerful HTML5 base theme framework utilizing tools like Sass, Compass, Grunt, Bower, Ruby Version Manager, Bundler and
         more.
1
/home/timmy/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/timmy in PATH, mode 040777
/home/timmy/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/timmy in PATH, mode 040777
/home/timmy/.gem/ruby/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /home/timmy in PATH, mode 040777
    error sass/first.no-query.scss (Line 3 of sass/first.styles.scss: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-normalize-1.5/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/toolkit-2.6.0/stylesheets
  Sass::Globbing::Importer)
    error sass/first.normalize.scss (Line 8: File to import not found or unreadable: toolkit/border-box.
Load paths:
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-normalize-1.5/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/toolkit-2.6.0/stylesheets
  Sass::Globbing::Importer)
    error sass/first.styles.scss (Line 3: File to import not found or unreadable: breakpoint.
Load paths:
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  /srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/susy-2.1.3/sass
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-normalize-1.5/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-rgbapng-0.2.1/lib/stylesheets
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/toolkit-2.6.0/stylesheets
  Sass::Globbing::Importer)
Compilation failed in 3 files.

07:11:22 - INFO - Guard::Compass is waiting to compile your stylesheets.
07:11:22 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.
07:11:22 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/srv/http/drupal-7.31/sites/all/themes/first'
[1] guard(main)> help
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.
here is the solution:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2323235#comment-9069731